# Como gravar uma lista vindo de um Option

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
echo "<select id='posto[]' name='posto[]' multiple='multiple'>";
    foreach ($postos as $lista) {
        echo '<option value=' . $lista->getCodigoPosto() . '>' . $lista->getNomePosto() . '</option>';
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</select>";
```

Dentro de um form com o method GET, quando o usuário faz o Submit eu pego os códigos que ele selecionou no OPTION e coloco em uma variavel como se fosse uma lista:

```
$postosSelecionados = $_REQUEST['posto'];
```

Assim passo essa lista para dentro de um método de gravação:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['posto'])) {
        if (UsuarioCadastradoDAO::aprovar($codigo, $aprovador, $postosSelecionados) == FALSE) {
            echo "alert('Ocorreu algum erro ao aprovar, favor tentar novamente.');</script>";
        }
    }
```

Veja a método:

```
public static function aprovar($codUsuarioAprovado, $codUsuarioAprovador, $listaDePostos) {
        try {
            $banco = new Banco();
            $banco->setComandoSQL("INSERT INTO `UsuarioMasterAprovado` (`IdUsuario`, `IdUsuarioAprovador`, `DataAprovacao`) VALUES (:UsuarioCadastrado,:UsuarioAprovador, CURDATE()); UPDATE `Usuario` SET `Aprovado` = 1 WHERE IdUsuario = :UsuarioCadastrado");

            $parametros = array(
                ':UsuarioCadastrado' => $codUsuarioAprovado,
                ':UsuarioAprovador' => $codUsuarioAprovador,
            );

            $banco->ExecutaSQLPreparada($parametros);

            foreach ($listaDePostos as $lista) {

                $banco->setComandoSQL("INSERT INTO `Usuario_Posto`(`Posto_idPosto`, `UsuarioMasterAprovado_IdUsuario`) VALUES (:idPostos,LAST_INSERT_ID()");

                $parametros = array(
                    ':idPostos' => $lista
                );

                $banco->ExecutaSQLPreparada($parametros);
            }
            return TRUE;

        } catch (Exception $ex) {           
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Porem algo esta errado e não estou conseguindo identificar o erro, pois não esta gravando no banco de dados.

Comment: Aparece algum erro? o auto commit está ligado? verifique se `ExecutaSQLPreparada()` retorna algum erro.

Comment: O.o não faz `return false;` no catch pelo menos mostra a exception, assim você sabe pelo menos por onde começar.

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando um parênteses:

> $banco->setComandoSQL("INSERT INTO `Usuario_Posto`(`Posto_idPosto`,
>   `UsuarioMasterAprovado_IdUsuario`) VALUES
>   (:idPostos,LAST_INSERT_ID()");

Correção:

$banco->setComandoSQL("INSERT INTO `Usuario_Posto`(`Posto_idPosto`, `UsuarioMasterAprovado_IdUsuario`) VALUES (:idPostos,LAST_INSERT_ID()**)**");

Comment: Boa, mas ainda não deu certo...